# Why does my USB audio device have problems with Google Hangouts?

Tags: audio, usb, microphone, google-hangouts

The audio sent to the person I'm talking to is very faint when using my USB audio headset and Google Hangouts, even if I turn the level up high in System Preferences. In Skype, everything is normal. What could be going on?

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)

10.10.2

Plantronics .Audio 478 Stereo USB Headset

Chrome

**update:** it seems that refreshing window (essentially re-joining the hangout) causes the correct mic to be detected.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've selected the Plantronics device in the mic chooser window in the Hangouts settings once the Hangout has begun (gear icon.)

[image]

Change the default setting (which should be the internal mic on the Mac if there is one:)

[image]

To Plantronics:

[image]

(I have the Blue Snowball connected in this screen cap.)

Comment: yep, i've done all that :\ see my update above